# DRF, in perform_authentication() the test for request.user is set to an empty string only when multiple tests are run

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

When I run a test by itself the test always passes, but when run even with one other test in the same test class it fails. I've tracked down the cause to the perform_authentication() method not having the AnonymousUser set instead, it is set to an empty string. This is not happening on all tests but maybe 20% of the 415 tests I've written. The change I made to the code was to use the Authorization header and removed the code that put credentials in the body of the login request. This should not have affected most of the tests that are now failing.

If I override the perform_authentication() by catching the exception and just exiting the method the test works fine, but this is not what I want to do obviously.

I would show code, but am not sure what to show. The tests have many layers since the same tests need to be done on many endpoints.

Does anybody have a better idea as to how this authorization works?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a rest_framework.APITestCase.

```
self.client.credentials(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION='Bearer ' + token)
```

Comment: The login that I've implemented is only for the SPA website, not the API directly so there are no tokens used. There will be tokens used when accessing the API as a service. To authenticate in tests I'm just using the `client.force_authenticate()` method.

Comment: I tried your suggestion with Basic auth, but I still have the same exact issue.